# Cannot get posted variables to echo in the form

Tags: php, forms, variables, post

It seems my code is correct, however the posted variables in the form will not echo in the update user settings page in the form. I have echoed the posted ids from the input in the database but I cannot get the variables to show.
I have done this in Codeigniter fine but am trying to do it in pure php with my own framework.

$users = new Users($db); comes from my init.php file that is called at the beginning of the file below.

```
   when I 
   <?php var_dump($user['first_name'])?> 
   I get Null

   <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['first_name']) )
    {echo htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['first_name']));} else { echo
    $user['first_name']; }?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

Hoi Stephen,

Try `print_r($_POST["first_name"]);` instead of var_dump();

or just for all:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

best regards ....

Answer (score 0):

add this at the top of your html page

```
@extract($_REQUEST);
```

and put is just to check and after checking remove the below line
print_r($_REQUEST);

```
hope this help .
```